# Getting songs from spotify api

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

So I have this code

```
export const load = async ({fetch}) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let playlists: Playlist[] = [];
    const ress = await fetch('api/token');
    const access_token = await ress.text();
    console.log("The access " + access_token)
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const getPlaylists = async (access_token: string) => {
        console.log("second access + " + access_token)
        const response = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
            }
        });
        
        console.log("before")
        if (!response.ok) {
            console.log('there has been an error')
        }
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        let next = data.next
        let items = data.items
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
        let total = data.total
        while (next) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
            for (const i of total) {
                const playlist: Playlist = {
                    name: items.name,
                    id: items.id,
                    songs: items.tracks
                }
                playlists.push(playlist);
                
                const res = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists', {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token }
                });
                
                const data_second = await res.json()
                next = data_second.next
                items = data_second.items
                total = data_second.total
            }
        }
    };
    getPlaylists(access_token)
    return { playlists: playlists }
}
```

So I get an error :  https://pastebin.com/qrgxFKfv
but I don't get how since I pass in the access token and I have checked to make sure that the access token in the getPlaylists method is valid.

https://pastebin.com/vvLWPJvj
I am confused how there is no name attribute on the data response since it is there in the docuemnetation: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists

Extra info: my playlist type:
https://pastebin.com/CGVK9hHC

I have checked if the access token is valid and it seems to be valid and I have looked at the spotify api docs and there should be a name attribute on the response

Comment: This is what worked for me: https://pastebin.com/XVDZ5Jgx

Comment: And this : https://pastebin.com/nPfXK3Ei

Comment: First one is getting the refresh token from the cookies and getting a new access token and the second one gets the spotify data in the sveltekit route